# How to let child process wait for signal?

Tags: c, linux, process, operating-system, multiprocessing

In the following code, I created 3 child processes. I want parent to complete `[some code 1]` before let the parent and 3 children continue simultaneously, and wait for all children to die before continue to `[some code 3]`.

But obviously, when running the code, sometimes children start their own `[some code x]` before SIGSTOP is sent. Now I am **not** allowed to use `sleep()`. What can I do to make sure children wait before parent finishes `[some code 1]`?

```
    pid_t fpid1 = fork();
    if (fpid1 > 0) { // parent
        kill(fpid1, SIGSTOP);
        pid_t fpid2 = fork();
        if (fpid2 > 0) { // parent
            kill(fpid2, SIGSTOP);
            pid_t fpid3 = fork();
            if (fpid3 > 0) { // parent
                kill(fpid3, SIGSTOP);
                [some code 1];
                kill(fpid1, SIGCONT);
                kill(fpid2, SIGCONT);
                kill(fpid3, SIGCONT);
                [some code 2];
                while(wait(NULL) > 0);
                [some code 3];
            }
            else if (fpid3 == 0) { // child 3
                [some code 4];
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if (fpid2 == 0) { // child 2
            [some code 5];
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else if (fpid1 == 0) { // child 1
        [some code 6];
        exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would delaying the calls to fork help? Something like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(void)
{
    puts("some code 1");

    puts("some code 2");

    pid_t fpid1 = fork();
    if (fpid1 == 0) {
        puts("some code 6");
        exit(0);
    }

    pid_t fpid2 = fork();
    if (fpid2 == 0) {
        puts("some code 5");
        exit(0);
    }

    pid_t fpid3 = fork();
    if (fpid3 == 0) {
        puts("some code 4");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (wait(NULL) > 0);
    puts("some code 3");
}
```

Instead of some code 1-6 running in any order only some code 4-6 should like this. This also has the side effect of removing nesting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personnaly always respect this pattern when using fork: i hope it could help you

```
if (fork == -1) { 
    // error // 
} else if (fork == 0) { 
    // child processing // 
    kill(getpid, SIGKILL)
} else {
    waitpid(pid, status, -YOUR OPTION-);
}
```